# HTML5 browser player on youtube video

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube

I would love to know if anyone got some experience on Youtube API's?

Cause i've been wondering if it's possible to embed an youtube video with HTML5 parameters, changing the player to the Browser default player!

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

While this is technically possible (see for example the YouTube downloader browser plugins that generate a proper link/URL for you), it most probably violates the YouTube API Terms of Service:

> **II. Prohibitions**
>
> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to:
>
> ...
>
> access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by YouTube;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms